# error while loading shared libraries: libjvm.so in hadoop yarn mpi app

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am using mpich2/yarn in https://github.com/alibaba/mpich2-yarn (this is a application running on Hadoop YARN that enables MPI programs running on Hadoop YARN clusters)

for my command:

```
hadoop jar mpich2-yarn-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -a ./sssp -M 256 -m 256 -n 3
```

when exec the program having follow error:

```
17/03/08 07:53:57 INFO client.Client: [stderr]/home/ubuntu/hdfstmp/mpiexecs/appattempt_1488955404934_0003_000001/MPIExec: error while loading shared libraries: libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

but I have updated below properties in my `.bashrc`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

so what's wrong with it . could someone tell me ? thanks